# If we use domain name instead of ip address i am getting 405 error

Tags: android, dns

I am sending an HTTP post request in postman.

the first request is using DNS

[image]

its posted succesfully. But, when i post it in the android studio using the same DNS but its showing 405 error as shown in the below image

[image]

I'm using DNS "http://flowjam.io", instead of IP "http://52.62.111.97:8080/wellness";

CODE

```
public void postCustomTonic(PostTonic postTonic, INetworkCallBack callBack) throws JSONException {
    mVolleyService = new VolleyService(callBack, AppController.APP_CONTEXT);
    mVolleyService.postDataVolley("Request", StringConstant.URL + "/tonic", new JSONObject(postTonic.toString()), callBack);
}
```

Comment: Add your code as text.

Comment: Please revert me back... I've added the code. @Fred....

Answer (score 0):

According to an nslookup and a DNS search for your domain name:

```
nslookup jamflowlist.io
Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address:  8.8.8.8

*** google-public-dns-a.google.com can't find jamflowlist.io: Non-existent domain
```

This tells me that the domain you are trying to hit is not yet registered. A WHOIS search tells me the same thing. Are you certain you have registered this domain name?

Also, according to your top picture you are hitting the URL flowjam.io not jamflowlist.io. These are two different domains.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have corrected my DNS and IP address. Please do check once again and revert me back.. @trejas

Comment: Just did a DNS lookup and your A record is pointing to the IP 184.168.221.30. This is not the same as the IP you have listed above.

Comment: but my DNS is redirecting to the following ip address http://52.62.111.97:8080/wellness/ @trejas

Comment: Unless you have a DNS entry on a local network your DNS entries are not pointing to 52.62.111.97. http://www.viewdns.info/dnsreport/?domain=flowjam.io